# Materialize: adding color to the color palett?

Tags: css, colors, sass, materialize

I am working on a project with the framework materialize and was wondering if it is possible to add colors to the color pallet. I am trying to implement custom colors through targeting the materialize variables style sheet with this.

```
$primary-color: color("materialize-red", "lighten-2") !default;
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !default;
$primary-color-dark: darken($primary-color, 15%) !default;
$secondary-color: color("teal", "lighten-1") !default;
$success-color: color("green", "base") !default;
$error-color: color("red", "base") !default;
$link-color: color("light-blue", "darken-1") !default;
```

I know how to change the colors and use the ones on the materialize pallet, but what if I need to use special colors from a client. As I have found the markup is very sensitive and you can not simply add a color inside.

I have tried this method below but does not work (I get an error thrown on line 59 in my `_variables.scss` file. something to do with "`lighten`")
https://github.com/ernestomancebo/materialize-custom-colors/blob/eb6d25f1712078d1348968fa7851e714668ef6c5/README.md

any type of help would be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but you have import materialize color variables before:

```
@import "materialize/components/color-variables";
$primary-color: color("materialize-red", "lighten-2") !default;
```

Best,
Alvaro.